# Why file.write() modifying the content of file in Python

Tags: python, string, file, io

Can anyone explain why the content of the file is being changed while writing?

And how to fix this

```
c='''#include <iostream>

int 
main ()
{
  std::cout << "Hello, world!\n"; <== this line is getting changed in output
  return 0;
}
'''
with open('x.cpp','w+') as f:
    f.write(c)
```

The output of the code

```
#include <iostream>

int 
main ()
{
  std::cout << "Hello, world!
"; <= modified while doing write operation
  return 0;
}
```

I am using Python 3.8

What I am doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: I assume you understand what `\n` means inside a string in C++, if you are trying to write a program that outputs C++ code into a file. What do you think it means in Python? Do you see why it would have the effect you observe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing your string to `raw` string. Since `\n` means a new line, you need to use raw strings instead

```
c=r'''#include <iostream>

int 
main ()
{
  std::cout << "Hello, world!\n"; <== this line is getting changed in output
  return 0;
}
'''
```

[Lexical  Analysis](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html)

> Unless an 'r' or 'R' prefix is present, escape sequences in string and
> bytes literals are interpreted according to rules similar to those
> used by Standard C.